# How to disable vscode autoformating extenstion tailwind css attribute

Tags: visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, autoformatting

I have a vs code Extention problem where it makes me frustrating while typing tailwind CSS

Here is before typing tailwind CSS attribute:

[image: Here is before typing tailwind CSS attribute]

After when I start typing the word go somewhere randomly within a class then I have to search and type the class

Here is After typing tailwind CSS attribute:

[image: Here is After typing tailwind CSS attribute]

**Please help me out with this problem**

Answer (score 2):

Check your `Auto Save` setting on VS Code.
VS Code automatically places the order of the Tailwind Class. In your case, you are having this problem because it is automatically saved and relocated before you completely type the Tailwind Class name.

So, in your case `off` will solve your problem.

Go into Settings with `Ctrl+Comma` ---> type `auto save` ---> `Files:Auto Save` : `off`

###### Other check point is `Headwind` option setup change.

A setting similar to the picture below will be retrieved when you typed `headwind`.

Then try changing option `Headwind: Run On Save` at the bottom of the picture.

[image]

Comment: Is there is any other way with out disable autosave?

Comment: Awesome , I switched off Headwind sort on save then I restarted the vscode worked like a charm even on autosave on